# Rails 3 PDFKit responds with format=pdf for every request after responding with pdf once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, format, pdfkit

I append .pdf to a view, e.g. `http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/edit/10024.html`

That page renders as a PDF. But then every page afterwards also renders as PDF, regardless of whether I append `.pdf` or `.html` or nothing to the end of the url. I'm not even sure how to debug this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug in PDFKit:
https://github.com/jdpace/PDFKit/issues#issue/66